# What does ?. and !. means in Angular template html file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nullpointerexception, operators

I am developing one Angular2 project and find this code in sample project.
what does `person?.name` and `person!.name` mean in this code?

```
ex)
let person = {
name: 'ali',
age: 18
}
```

Html template:

```
<label> {{ person?.name }} </label>
```

I am not sure if person?.name can work in .ts file also.
Does these operators work in Javascript also?
If Javascript doesn't support this, how can I manage same function?

Comment: Note that the code you posted *does not include use of the operators you're asking about.*

Comment: This question is not well formed at all. It's completely unclear what you are asking. Please fix or delete it.

Comment: Also note that TypeScript has documentation

Comment: What you're talking about there is part of [Angular's template syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths).

Answer (score 0):

> what does person?.name mean in this code

Its safe navigation operator covered here : https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-operators

> I am not sure if person?.name can work in .ts file also

No. Not yet. More here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16